# Chrome UI size too small

Tags: google-chrome, interface

I've installed Chrome in my laptop and works fine, but the user interface is too small for me. Some time ago, I made it bigger by modifying the file `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome-stable` and adding the flag `--force-device-scale-factor=n %U` (as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1116767/chrome-ui-size-zoom-levels-in-ubuntu-16-04)).

However, this solution doesn't work anymore with Ubuntu 17.10; I've even tried to launch Chrome with that flag from a terminal and the flag is marked as unknown. Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: n is supposed to be a number. What's the output that you get if you run `google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=1` from a terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file I mentioned in my question has two '`Exec=...`' statements. I managed to solve the problem by adding the flag in both of the statements.